# how to write the code to show and hide the data in if condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

In my angular application I have created the dashboard page In that created the map and right side placed the data to display something about the map (i.e created the circle in the map of 5km radius if the marker inside the circle show the details of the marker).

I have written the if loop for  the marker comes inside the circle it should be turned to red otherwise blue.

**In that condition I have to show exactly when the drone inside the circle I have to show some data in html.
If outside the data should be hidden.**

**component.ts**

```
function inQuadrant(quadrant,marker){
    var inPolygon02 = isMarkerInsidePolygon02(marker,quadrant);
  if(inPolygon){
    quadrant.setStyle({color: 'red'});
  }else{
    quadrant.setStyle({color: '#3388ff'});
  }
}
```

from the above code I have to show the data if it is red color(inside of circle)otherwise hide the data.

**component.html**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade " id="Drones">
  <ul class="list-group card"  id="dd">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let x of datas">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-3" >
          <div class="card-body">
  <img src="{{drone01.iconref}}" width="90" height="90">
  
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hidden` property.
Let me give you an example

Suppose, you have a `property` in your `component class`

`public isRed:boolean = true;`

In the component `html` file, you can bind the `hidden` property

```
<div [hidden]="!isRed">
</div>
```

It will hide this `div`, if `isRed` is set to `false` otherwise it will show the `div`.

Comment: I didn't understand can you please explain for the above if condition which I have mentioned the code.

Comment: create a property isRed in your ts file. And in the function inQuadrant(), if the value of inPolygon is true then set the value of isRed to true.